# Plotting mean as dashed line on histogram with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a histogram created from a pandas dataframe that I would like to plot a vertical dashed line representing the mean of the dataset. I have reviewed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180946/drawing-average-line-in-histogram-matplotlib), which is exactly the style I am looking for, however, I cannot figure out how to make it work with my code (below):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#import csv file into pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/my/file')

#calculating mean
m = df.mean()
#print(m)

#plotting histogram 
df.plot(kind='hist')
#plt.axvline(m, color = 'r', linestyle = 'dashed', linewidth = 2)
```

I end up receiving this error:

```
 ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Not sure what that means, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: My datafile is a csv with one column, first row is a header (string) and all subsequent 107 rows are values ranging from app. 1.0E+11 to 4.0E+11

---

Fake data (Python 2.7)

```
import io
import numpy as np
a = np.linspace(1, 4, num = 20)
s = 'E11\n'.join(map(str, a))
s += 'E11'
#print(s)
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(s))
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data file?

Comment: Posted a description above, does that help?

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?, can you post the complete Traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m` is a Pandas Series, it has an index and a value - Matplotlib must not know how to handle it.

```
>>> print m
1.0E11    2.578947e+11
dtype: float64
>>> type(m)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>>
```

The value of the mean is `m[0]` or `m.values`, so:

```
plt.axvline(m[0], color = 'r', linestyle = 'dashed', linewidth = 2)
#or
plt.axvline(m.values, color = 'r', linestyle = 'dashed', linewidth = 4)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use m.all() instead of m. and them use plt.show() for plt to draw your histogram. so the code will look like this:

```
#plotting histogram 
# df.plot(kind='hist')
plt.axvline(m.all(), color = 'r', linestyle = 'dashed', linewidth = 2)
plt.show()
```