# Adding mean, standard deviation etc. to a histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I'm not too sure if this is possible.
But I was wondering whether there is a way to add additional information onto the legend of a graph using matplotlib in python.

For example something like this:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Drawing average line in histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180946/drawing-average-line-in-histogram-matplotlib)

Comment: You can use `plt.text(x, y, f'mean:{np.mean(x_values):.2f}')` to put text on a certain x,y position.