# Plotting vertical line on an image clears the image leaving only the vertical lines

Tags: python

Hi All I want to plot vertical lines on a plotted image. I am using `ax.vlines()` to plot the vertical lines on the image, however the resulting plot clears the image leaving only the vertical lines on the figure as showed in the attached image. Any suggestions to correct this are welcomed. Below is my sample code:

```
def display_image(img, SavePath):
    vmin, vmax = np.min(img), np.max(img)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))
    img = ax.imshow(img, cmap='gray', aspect="auto", extent=[0, image.shape[1], img.shape[0]/10, 0], vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax    = divider.append_axes("right",size="5%",pad=0.05)
    plt.colorbar(img,ax=ax,cax=cax)
    plt.tick_params(labelsize=6)
    for label in  ax.get_xticklabels()+ax.get_yticklabels():
        label.set_fontsize(6)
    ax.vlines(x=[0, 120, 256],  ymin=2, ymax=0, colors='r')   ## this line plots the 3 vertical lines
    plt.savefig(SavePath+'Image', facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), 
                        edgecolor=fig.get_edgecolor(), transparent=True)
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhz3z.png)

Comment: What does `make_axes_locatable(ax)` do?

Comment: It takes the axes and creates a divider for it @asdf

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful here.

Comment: Also, consider using `axvline` instead

Comment: Link: [`axvline`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvline.html); see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180946/drawing-average-line-in-histogram-matplotlib/16181102#16181102, for example.  One drawback of `axvline` is that it draws only one line per call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `ymax` argument of `ax.vlines` to the height of the image, because right now you only draw a vertical line from pixels 0 to 2 of your image. The following code works for me (`make_axes_locatable(ax)` commented out because I don't know what it does):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = np.random.random(size=(300, 300))

vmin, vmax = np.min(img), np.max(img)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))
img_ax = ax.imshow(img, cmap='gray', aspect='auto', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
# divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
# cax    = divider.append_axes("right",size="5%",pad=0.05)
plt.colorbar(img_ax, ax=ax)  # cax=cax)
plt.tick_params(labelsize=6)
for label in  ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels():
    label.set_fontsize(6)
ax.vlines(x=[0, 120, 256], ymin=0, ymax=img.shape[0] - 1, colors='r')   # this line plots the 3 vertical lines
plt.show()
```

Produces the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Does not work on my end. From the attached image on my post, you can see that the y-axis has been scaled down from 201 to 2.01 using the ```extent``` variable in the ```imshow```

Comment: I think I have seen the reason. I will get it fixed. Thanks for your input @asdf